# "TypeError: o.Z[e] is undefined" when deploying next js application onto vercel

Tags: github, next.js, deployment, backend, vercel

I have deployed a next js full stack (connected with mongodb) application onto vercel. During the deployment process there were no errors but when I opened the website after it was deployed, the screen was white and there was a text in the middle saying 'Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).'. On opening the browser console all there was, was 'TypeError: o.Z[e] is undefined' as in the screenshot below:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbjhu.png). [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TDkK.png)

I tried searching on the internet for any solution but couldn't find any. Anyone who has gone through this or know anything about this, his/her response would be appreciated. Thanks